# Meaning of the hidden state in Keras LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm

Since I am new to deep learning this question may be funny to you. but I couldn't visualize it in the mind. That's why I am asking about it.

I am giving a sentence as the vector to the LSTM, Think I have a sentence contains 10 words. Then I change those sentences to the vectors and giving it to the LSTM.

The length of the LSTM cells should be 10. But in most of the tutorials, I have seen they have added 128 hidden states. I couldn't understand and visualize it. What's that the word means by LSTM layer with `"128-dimensional hidden state"`

for example:

```
X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(embeddings)
```

The summery of this looks

```
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 10, 128)           91648
```

Here It looks like 10 LSTM cells are added but why are that 128 hidden states there? Hope you may understand what I am expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
If you are more familiar with Convolutional Networks, you can thick of the size of the LSTM layer (128) is the equivalent to the size of a Convolutional layer. The 10 only means that the size of your input (lenght of your sequence is 10)

**Longer Answer:**
You can check this article for more detail [article about RNNs](https://towardsdatascience.com/recurrent-neural-networks-rnns-3f06d7653a85).

In the left image, a LSTM layer is represented with (`xt`) as the input with output (`ht`). The feedback arrow shows that there is some kind of memory inside the cell.

In practice in Keras (right image), this model is "unrolled" to give the whole input `xt` in parallel to our layer.

So when your summary is:
    lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 10, 128)           91648
It means that your input sequence is 10 (`x0,x1,x2,...,x9`), and that the size of your LSTM is 128 (128 will be the dimension of your output `ht`)

[image]

Comment: so it means that there can be the small number of inputs and a large number of outputs. So What I didn't understand is in your image number of xt and number of ht are same. so when there's a large number of ht how is it produces . could you please give a visulaization to it. @Daniel

Comment: Consider reading the cited article, maybe with the formulas it will be more clear to you.

Comment: The link you given is not available currently please provide some alternative link if possible.